# Combining count and distinct

Tags: mysql

I am having some difficulty using COUNT and DISTINCT. 
I have a mysql table in the following format:

```
phone_number     language_id       
    100               1
    200               2
    100               1
    100               2
    200               3
```

How can I get the count in the following format:

```
phone_number     language_id       count
    100               1              2
    100               2              1
    200               2              1
    200               3              1
```

Does it requires a sub-query to get the desired output? I tried combining count and distinct but still no luck, so I was wondering if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you explain the count value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `phone_number`, `language_id`, COUNT(*) AS `count` 
FROM `test`
GROUP BY `phone_number`, `language_id`
```

Comment: Happy to help. I edited my answer slightly to include backticks, which is always a good idea especially if a column name is named the same as a MySQL keyword (such as `count`).

Answer (score 0):

This returns you only duplicates(or more), if you want all, just delete HAVING clause

```
SELECT phone_number, language_id, count(*)AS count 
FROM name_of_your_table 
GROUP BY phone_number,language_id
HAVING count(*)>1
```

Comment: If you want to see all, not only duplicates just omit "HAVING count(*)>1"